# Doctrine Tree getting disorganized after changing child position

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I create three-levels nested tree ( with only three entities ) that looks like this:

```
1 (lft 1, rgt:6)
 -2 (lft 2, rgt:5)
   -3 (lft 3, rgt:4)
```

and then I try to move node ( with id=3, i.e. ) from the third level to the second level as, let's say second child with this piece of code:

```
/* this line can be commented - it doesn't work with it either */ $chapter->setParent($parentEntity);
$repo->persistAsFirstChildOf($chapter, $parentEntity);
$repo->moveDown($chapter, 1);
```

As a result I got the tree that goes like this:

```
1 ( lft:-4, rgt:6 )
 -3 (lft: 5, rgt:6)
 -2 (lft 7, rgt:5)
```

instead of this:

```
1 (lft 1, rgt:6)
 -2 (lft 2, rgt:5)
 -3 (lft 3, rgt:4)
```

and child which should become second in order becomes first. As You can see, lft values aren't proper. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You should update node and set new parent by gedmo TreeListener (get it by NestedTreeRepository->listener) :

```
<?php
class YourNestedTreeRepository extends NestedTreeRepository

    .......

    /**
     * @param Node $node
     * @param Node $newParent
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setNewParent($node, $newParent)
    {
        $meta = $this->getClassMetadata();
        $this->listener
            ->getStrategy($this->_em, $meta->name)
            ->updateNode($this->_em, $node, $newParent)
        ;
    }
```

and then, anywhere in your code:

```
//set as first child of a new parent - Tree hierarchy, it doesn't touch ORM relation
$repo->setNewParent($node, $newParent);
//set new parent and save. It updates ORM relation only, doesn't touch Tree hierarchy
$node->setParent($newParent);
$entityProvider->save($node); // or $entityManager->flush()
//additionaly move it down
if ($yourCondition) {
    $result = $repo->moveDown($node, $position);
}
```

Comment: "or" refers to setParent || moveDown or to setNewParent && setParent || moveDown? I can't check whether the code is proper right now.

Comment: @mmmm
I've updated my "example code". It should be more clearly now.

Answer (score 0):

You actually are OK there.

I think left/right values does not matter there since your order is still ok.

Your probleme is that you call

```
$repo->moveDown($chapter, 1);
```

This function will make your `$chapter` to move at next position (second one in your case).

Delete the call to moveDown and try it again.

As far as lft and rgt attributes are concerned, adding/removing node may recompute them.

If it's a real matter to you, then try calling (i'm not sur about this):

```
$repo->recover();
$em->flush(); // ensures cache clean
```

Comment: well I'm not ok, I get wrong order, as I mentioned it. Instead entity with id 3 getting into second position it's in first. I call moveDown() to move to next position. Maybe I haven't said it clearly, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Actually guys, I've chosen bad tree type. **Don't** use **nested** when You want to change children position often.